# Change Website font style

Tags: html, css

I m using one of the Font for my website i.e. "Aparajita". Which is not required to be available in every system through which my site is getting accessed.

My problem is it look's different when this font is installed on the browsing PC and some horrible when the same font is not getting installed.

How should i resolve this issue.

Should i install "Aparajita" Font on my hosting Server or what else...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **CSS3** `@font-face` **property** for use custom font in your website and with the help of this your font will look same on all computers wheather they have insallted that font or not....

You can write like this :-

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

[**Or Read More About how to use custom fonts for our websites.....**](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-font-face-or-how-to-use-a-custom-font-for-your-website)

Comment: in short i need to install "Aparajita" font on my web server and add reference as you mentioned above...

Comment: Hey Sham you don't need to install "Aparajita" font on your web server. You just need to make sure that have that required font with all formats in your fonts folder. Using @font-face in your CSS you can easily run any of font on your website and for more once you will read the complete article as i mentioned in my answer you will get the complete idea how to use the custom fonts in your website just read its really nice and smooth process not really tough :-).......

Comment: Hi Shailender thanks for the help, steps of the suggested site is awesome. I have one doubt, how should i verify whether "Aparajita" font is free or not.

Comment: its free i think i have checked it on google its free available for download so i think should not have any issue with this.... see the links is this your font :- http://fontzone.net/font-details/Aparajita/

Comment: @Sham, a font is free for use as a downloadable font, if the font author says so.

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure you have legal rights to the font.
2. Make the font available on your web server (i.e. put it in a directory from which it can be served in response to an HTTP request, the same way you would an image or stylesheet).
3. Reference it in your CSS using `@font-face`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@font-face

[Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface) has many free fonts and [font-related tools](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) abstracts the whole process is makes it quite easy.

Now that you (hopefully) know what terms to search for, you can find many examples on SO of using custom fonts.

Comment: how should i verify whether "Aparajita" font is available some where on http://developer.mozilla.org site, so that i can add diret reference... or need to install it on my web server

Comment: You don't need to install it on your web server. You need to make sure it's available for download. Using @font-face, your CSS stylesheet will point to the font file and automatically download it.

Comment: Alternatively, if you upload your "Aparajita" font [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) you can generate the CSS you need to use it.

Comment: ok i have uploaded my font and get downloaded some files, so now should i just upload .css file on my web server or any modification i need to do...

Comment: Yes, make sure your site's CSS file has the `@font-face` rule, and upload the font files. @Shailender Arora's example shows how you would do it if your font files were uploaded to the same directory as your CSS file.

Answer (score -2):

`<font face="Your font_family">`

Here it is for font style.

> `<FONT SIZE=7 COLOR=RED>word</FONT></U></B>`

Comment: You will have to download the desire font which you want and add that font in from control Panel

Comment: 1) This doesn't resolve the custom font issue, 2) `font` is "entirely obsolete, and must not be used by authors" (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features), 3) the markup is ugly (all caps, unquoted attributes), and 4) it's invalid (stray `u` and `b` closing tags)