# How to add font to a web page

Tags: html, css

How do you add a font to a page.

For example lets say I have a particular `.TTF` file.

And I want to use this file on a particular webpage. Now with all browsers processing different fonts differently is it possible in CSS to add the "font file" in the `font-family` tag.

I'm sorry if this is unsolvable or unbelievably simple I'm  a newbie to CSS.

Comment: I would recommend not to use any special fonts... it will make your page load slower.

Comment: @Ladineko So will images and css and any other resource. Best to avoid it all, right? Who cares about design anyway?

Comment: @peirix Images, css wont effect the speed that much. Ofcourse every element takes down speed. but a special font takes it down alot cause every single character has to be loaded for all the text.

Comment: @Ladineko You're talking about marginal stuff here. You can easily get your font files down to 100kb each, and you usually only need 3. That's not a heavy load. It'll be cached. And you can take measurements to ease this. http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/
Avoiding custom fonts for that reason is not a good option, imo. Btw, do you have any reference to back up that every character for the entire text needs to "load"? This is new to me, and I'm not sure I believe it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Website font style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619007/change-website-font-style)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the font folder and save all the font files

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Archer-Semibold';
        src: url('fonts/archer-semibold-pro.eot');
        src: url('fonts/archer-semibold-pro.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url('fonts/archer-semibold-pro.woff') format('woff'),
                 url('fonts/archer-semibold-pro.ttf') format('truetype'),
                 url('fonts/archer-semibold-pro.svg#archer-semibold-pro') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

.menu {
  font-family: Archer-Semibold;
}
```

`url('fonts/archer-semibold-pro.eot')` is use for IE 9 and `url('fonts/archer-semibold-pro.eot?#iefix')` is used for IE 6 to 8

Comment: Just one question why have you given so many formats. Is it because different browsers use different fonts?

Comment: ofcourse. View this [article](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/fixing-ie9-font-face-problems).

Comment: Nice one. Correct answer for the browser fix .

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) should help you.

You declare your new font with:

```
@font-face { 
  font-family: Delicious; 
  src: url('Delicious-Roman.otf'); 
}
```

Then reference it with

```
h1 {
  font-family: Delicious;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `.ttf`-file that you own, you can go to a site that will make web fonts for you (for instance font-squirrel: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

You'll get a zip with the fonts, a CSS-file with some font-face declerations. That should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `@font-face`

```
@font-face {
    font-family:font-name;
    src: url(path-to-font/font-name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@charset "utf-8";       //file encoding

@font-face {
font-family: 'GoodDogRegular';
src: local("GoodDog Regular");
url('fonts/gooddog-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

You can now use this font like a regular font in your CSS.

```
.menu {
font-family:GoodDogRegular;
color:#dd0000;
font-size: 36px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```